# how to find the range of any given integer by a specified step with recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, ecmascript-6, range

I want to use recursion to find the range of a given integer by a specified step.

```
  given number --> -20 
  step --> 4
  returns --> [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 ]
```

Thus far, I was able to create a recursive function to return the corresponding results:

```
function range(num,step,res=[]) {
  const s = num < step ? step : -step; 
  if (num === step + s) return res;
  return num === step ? [...res,num] : range(num+s,step,[...res,num]);
}

console.log(range(5,1)); // [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
console.log(range(-8,2)); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2 ]
console.log(range(-20,4)); // [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 ]
```

However, the following invocations returns stackoverflow

```
console.log(range(-7,2)); // stackoverflow!
console.log(range(11,5)); // stackoverflow!
```

I know something is wrong with the code, but I just couldn't figure out what it is. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction or show me what I'm doing wrong. Million thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to TazHinkle's control flow I was able to solve the problem as follow:

```
function range(num,step,res=[]) {
  const s = num < step ? step : -step;
  if (num > step && num < step) return res;
  if (num < step && num + s > step) return [...res,num];
  return num === step ? [...res,num] : range(num+s,step,[...res,num]);
}

console.log(range(5,1)); // [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
console.log(range(-8,2)); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2 ]
console.log(range(-20,4)); // [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, 0, 4 ]
console.log(range(11,5)); // [ 11, 6, 1 ]
console.log(range(-7,2)); // [ -7, -3, -5, -1, 1 ]
console.log(range(-9,4)); // [ -9, -5, -1, 3 ]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this function is supposed to do?  It looks like you want it to return the numbers between `num` and `0`, with a step-size of `step`, but the example line `console.log(range(-8,2)); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2 ]` goes past zero.  The other two examples stop just before zero.

Comment: StackOverflow means you have recursed too many times and the computer has run out of memory. From a glance, it looks like you ran into an infinite loop and couldn't exit properly.

Comment: Why is `0` sometimes included in the result and sometimes not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case range(-7,2) cannot resolve in the current version because it will infinitely step between 1 and 3 (because it's stepping by 2 and trying to arrive at 2, but it's never going to).
You can make it give up when it goes past with something like this:

```
function range(num,step,res=[]) {
    const s = num < step ? step : -step;
    const forward = num < step ? true : false;
    if (num === step + s) return res;
    if(forward) {
        if(num + s > step) {
            return [...res,num]
        }
        return num === step ? [...res,num] : range(num+s,step,[...res,num]);
    }else {
        if(num + s < step) {
            return [...res,num]
        }
        return num === step ? [...res,num] : range(num+s,step,[...res,num]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite close actually :) If only we can only get `range(-7,2); // [ -7, -3, -5, -1, 1 ]` instead of `range(-7,2); // [ -7, -3, -5, -1, 1, 3 ]`

Comment: Alright, this is pretty easily fixed.  You just check for num + s instead of just num.  I've edited above to reflect that.

Comment: Your tweaks was almost there except for `range(11,5);  // [ 11, 6 ]` which should've been `range(11,5); // [ 11, 6, 1 ]` Nonetheless, we did it my friend. Thanks to your control flow, I was finally able crack this algorithm :) I'll update the code above and hopefully this can help someone someday... Once again, big thank you TazHinkle. Nothing beats pair coding to tackle a problem 

Answer (score 0):

This is under the assumption that your goal is to start at the first parameter then step down until the last number is 0, 1, or -1 (basically as close to zero as possible).

First, instead of flip-floping the `step` to/from neg/pos, convert neg to pos and set a flag for neg steps:

```
if (num < 0) {
  n = Math.abs(num);
  neg = true;
} else n = num;
```

Remove this extra step which left no way for odd numbered parameters to stop:

<s>`if (num === step + s) return res;`</s>

The only difference in this line is `<` instead of `===`. That'll take odd numbers closer to 0 and even numbers to zero:

```
let result = n < step ? [n, ...res] : rangeToZero(n -step, step, [n, ...res]);
```

Finally, if the `neg == true` we make each number a negative (it feels like cheating):

```
if (neg) {
  return result.map(N => -Math.abs(N));
}
```

```js
function rangeToZero(num, step, res=[]) {
  let n, neg = false; 
  if (num < 0) {
    n = Math.abs(num);
    neg = true;
  } else n = num;

  let result = n < step ? [n, ...res] : rangeToZero(n -step, step, [n, ...res]);
  if (neg) {
    return result.map(N => -Math.abs(N));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(rangeToZero(5,1)); // [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]
console.log(rangeToZero(-8,2)); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0 ]
console.log(rangeToZero(-20,4)); // [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, 0 ]
console.log(rangeToZero(10, 3)); // [ 10, 7, 4, 1 ]
console.log(rangeToZero(-7,2)); // [ -7, -3, -5, -1 ]
console.log(rangeToZero(11,5)); // [ 11, 6, 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I do want to go past 0, meaning `range(-20,4); // [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 ]or range(-8,2); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2 ]` Furthermore, when testing your code, it would return `-0` for example 2 & 3 --> `rangeToZero(-8,2)); // [ -8, -6, -4, -2, -0 ]` and `rangeToZero(-20,4); // [ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, -0 ]` respectively.

Comment: The only way I could see  having variable lengths is to add another parameter. Your question wasn't clear on what constitutes a range. Because of those conditions being `===` instead of `<=` or `>=`  your function bypasses that `===` and continues after `0` if the step is an odd number or if `num` is odd or ...I haven't  tested it every aspect because the design was flawed. So there's no practical use of getting different lengths when you pass odd or even parametters. Have you seen the results in my answer? There are no `-0`.  The parameter  2 and 3 is an edge case I didn't bother with...cont.

Comment: cont....maybe add this check: `if (n < step && n - step < 0) return null` around the top of the function.

Comment: Continuing on what a range should be: a min and max so if `num` is -20 which is ABS 20 and all the directions are to 0. That is logical and coincides with certain restrictions that all returned values have in common.  `[ -20, -16, -12, -8, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 ]` makes no sense nor does `[ -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2 ]` because they do not share common boundries not that useful.